# Понимает ли стек Lua потоки ? или же его нужно делать разделяемым ресурсом?

Tags: c++, lua

Доброго времени суток. У меня следующий вопрос:
Использую Lua_Api для плюсов. Lua 5.1.

1) Есть приложение, оно стартуется первым.

2) Приложение вызывает скрипт луа и определяет несколько функций запускащихся в разных потоках.

3) Сам скрипт Lua выглядит как вызов Dll, написанной на C++.

```
require("My dll");
```

Внутри Dll я подписываюсь на эти 2 функции и получается что вызов из терминала, отправляется в Dll и вызываются функции из моей Dll.

3.1) Внутри Dll переменная Lua вынесена в глобальную и к ней подключаются еще нескольку функций, которые могут выполняться, как в каком либо из двух потоков запускаемых первым приложением (пункт № 1), так ив каком либо своем потоке...

---

Собственно из всего описанного вытек вопрос, нужно ли мне в каждой из функций (включая те что запускаются как коллбеки с программы № 1) делать луа как разделяемый ресурс ? Или же стек сам поймет что его вызывают из другого потока и не будет глючить не чего?

---

Comment: Нет, сам не поймёт. Надо защищать от параллельного использования.

Comment: @zed А защищать как те что из терминала вызываются, так и те что глобальную переменную используют следует ? 

Я пока что только те что глобальную переменную используют защитил, думаю стоит ли защищать те что из терминала (пенкт # 1)  приходят или же нет (они как коллбеки работают, если есть событие в терминале, то функция вызывается), там же вроде своя ссылка помещается `int(lua_State* L)`?

Comment: У меня там просто получается так, что один поток подписан на функцию из терминала которая в бесконечном while с паузой крутится, а другие время от времени вызываются как коллбеки в разных потоках

Comment: Приведите минимальный воспроизводимый код и я подскажу, где именно надо расставить локи.

Comment: @zed Благодарю Вас за помощь. Похоже понял как лучше сделать. На каждый новый поток буду создавать поток Луа.`L_ptr=lua_newthread(L); `на на функции которые могут быть использованы в потоках созданных внутри dll буду делать блокировку как разделяемые ресурсы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua делался как небольшой и переносимый язык, в связи с чем он не является потокобезопасным. Более того, `lua_newthread` не имеет прямого отношения к многопоточности. Нельзя добиться того, чтобы lua код выполнялся параллельно в одном `lua_state`. Всё зависит от вашей цели - либо вы реализуете C функцию для блокировки, но в таком случае lua код будет работать лишь последовательно, либо создаёте несколько `lua_state` (один на поток), реализуя передачу данных между ними.